# retrieving data from firebase: FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**JSON FIREBASE DATA:**
here added the Data of the firebase database

```
 {
  "login" : {
    "9847002233" : {
      "name" : "Saj",
      "number" : "9847002233",
      "password" : "123456"
    },
   "9847123123" : {
     "name" : "jishnu",
     "number" : "9847123123",
     "password" : "123456"
   }
  }
}
```

**Model Class**
this class is only for Login credentials

```
public class LoginData {
String number;
String password;
String name;

public LoginData(String name , String number, String password) {
    this.number = number;
    this.password = password;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

**CODE FOR READ:**
I tried to retrieve data that time error occurred because of returning type is entirely different, am expecting same as the LoginData type the return some another HashMap

```
           firebaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String,LoginData>> mapType = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, LoginData>>() { };
                Map<String,LoginData> logindatalist = dataSnapshot.getValue(mapType);
                if (logindatalist!=null) {
                    for (LoginData data: logindatalist.values()) {
                        System.out.println(data.getName());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```

**ERROR LOG**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: myapp.com.myapplication, PID: 30987
    com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
        at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:208)
        at myapp.com.myapplication.Login$2.onDataChange(Login.java:68)
        at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45)
        at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
        at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class myapp.com.myapplication.model.LoginData]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
        at [Source: java.io.StringReader@edca2f8; line: 1, column: 16]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:984)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringMap(MapDeserializer.java:432)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:314)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:26)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2041)
        at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:206)
            ... 11 more
```

Comment: where does your `firebaseReference` points to ?

Comment: I think you need to add default constructor (without parameter) in your model class `public LoginData() {}`
From https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data, // _Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)_

Comment: The "No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class myapp.com.myapplication.model.LoginData]" message indeed indicates that your missing the mandatory no-argument constructor. Can you provide that as answer @Wilik?

Comment: sure thing @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the default constructor (without parameter) in your model class.

```
public LoginData() {}
```